# Looking for architecture to download big files

Tags: architecture, microservices

I want to develop system to download very big files (from REST /streaming events/FTP etc) from big sources sites (Whois database, Shodan, Censys etc -  It's around 1-3TB file size split to 1GB~ file from each source).

The system should do:

1. Download the file from the source (from REST api/ftp etc)
2. Convert to csv format
3. Manipulate data (i.e: convert the time format to my time format)
4. Split and zip the big csv file to smallest csv files in Zip (I.e 10mb for each).

What I'm think about is to develop as Micro services concept and using RabbitMQ.

The first Micro service just download the file and write message to RabbitMQ with the file location indication.

The second convert the file to csv and write message to RabbitMQ with the new file.

The third manipulate the data (convert columns etc) and write message with the new csv file.

The fourth split and zip.

I just want to know if there is another design to develop this system, Maybe I should choose another design?

I would like to hear any suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: It will take 30+ hours to download a 1.3 TB file over a 100Mbps line, and way longer to process through it, though any process which does try to load it for processing will run out of memory and crash. Ergo, I don't think whether your system uses microservices or not is the limiting factor here.

Comment: @tomredfern I'm sorry I forgot to say that the 3TB files seperated to 1GB files

Comment: If you deployment is on AWS, you can think of SQS to ease the operations aspect of the MQ.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [Cadence Workflow](https://cadenceworkflow.io/) for your use case. Yes, you can build your process using RabbitMQ, but you end up implementing a lot of features that Cadence provides out of the box.

Cadence offers a lot of other advantages over using queues for task processing.

- Built it exponential retries with unlimited expiration interval
- Failure handling. For example it allows to execute a task that notifies another service if both updates couldn't succeed during a configured interval.
- Support for long running tasks
- Heartbeating to checkpoint progress of long running tasks.
- Ability to implement complex task dependencies. For example to implement chaining of calls or compensation logic in case of unrecoverble failures ([SAGA](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html))
- Gives complete visibility into current state of the update. For example when using queues all you know if there are some messages in a queue and you need additional DB to track the overall progress. With Cadence every event is recorded.
- Ability to cancel an update in flight.
- Distributed CRON support

See [the presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llmsBGKOuWI) that goes over Cadence programming model.